# How to Store 3D panorama data in Image?

Tags: data-structures, 3d, latex

We are thinking in [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/310211/13173) of the thread *Mouse Control of 360 Video in Beamer* how to store 3D data in a picture. Stepping size is 10 degrees. In matrix, it means 36x18 projections (=648 individual image files). All of them could be stored in a single image. However, we are not sure how. I can do 2D panorama viewer. I am trying to do the 3D viewer such that the result has a manageable size (so 10 degree step size).

### Proposal #1

ASCII example of equispaced font where 9 (=18/2) panorama pictures of the hemisphere on top of each other for each angle; everything can be in one picture

```
1 2 3 4 ... 34 35 36
___2D-panorama #1__ 1
___2D-panorama #2__ 2
________etc________ 3
___________________ 4
___________________ ...
___________________ 8
___2D-panorama_ #9_ 9
```

---

How to Store 3D panorama data in Image?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? It sounds like you are currently representing a panorama using 648 images captured by rotating the camera 10° in latitude and longitude, and you want to project and merge the 648 images into 1 that looks like this: https://cdn.eso.org/images/screen/potw1130a.jpg . It that correct? And what do you mean by 2D versus 3D panorama?

Comment: The 2D picture has less frames than wanted 3D case. Your first link is 2D panorama. 3D case has 648 frames. 3D panorama image has nine 2D panoramas stored on top of each other.